# IE8 addEventListener - Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

i am debugging a WPTheme for IE8.  It has a feature that loads a post inside a lightbox window, only the parent page scroll Y coordinates get reset to the top of the page. -- so when you close the lightbox the you are at top of the page... so you lose the place where you were just browsing.

here is the code that fires right before the scroll bar shoots to the top of the page. right before the lightbox pops up.

```
document.addEventListener("touchmove",function(t){var n=t.targetTouches?t.targetTouches[0]:t;e.x=n.pageX,e.y=n.pageY}):document.addEventListener("mousemove",function(t){e.x=t.pageX,e.y=t.pageY}),e}()
```

how can i rewrite this to be compatible with IE8?

Answer (score 1):

In IE 8 doesnt exist addEventListener. For that you must use attachEvent. You can use something like this for check what to use.

```
if (el.addEventListener) {
  el.addEventListener('click', modifyText, false); 
} else if (el.attachEvent)  {
  el.attachEvent('onclick', modifyText);
}
```

Comment: Please use proper words here. There is no character limit for answers, so there is no reason to use txtspk.